# Console/file logger library C++

Tags: c++, logging

Can you recommend me any logger library for C++ which makes possible to get colorful logs in console? I am using spdlog now but it doesn't support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [this version](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/tree/296623baa31898623bca0b866cc39f576b4ef93f), spdlog supports colors (added bool param to console logger constructor)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use [google-glog](https://github.com/google/glog). But I'm sure there are many more options out there if you just google for it.

Answer (score 0):

[quill](https://github.com/odygrd/quill) as of version 1.4.0 also supports terminal colours for macos/linux/windows.